# Does voltage drop limit the maximum current that can be draw?

Tags: current-limiting, ohms-law, voltage

I'm a newbie to this area. I'm having a few questions about the ohm law.

The given scenario is, In the circuit, there is a power source of 5V, and a resistor of 1 ohm. This means there will be 5A current come through the resistor, so the voltage drop is 5V.

First question: Assuming the power source is regulated, the voltage drop in the resistor is 5v, so it makes the voltage across the circuit is 0v. In this case, will the regulator offset for 5v of dropping to make the overall voltage back to 5v constantly?

Second question: Assuming, change the resistor value to 0.5 Ohm. In theory, it will draw 5v/0.5ohm=10A current, and the voltage drop is 10A/0.5ohm=20v instead. In practice, Will this ever happens? Because the power source is 5v only, it can't be lower 0v. There the maximum current is limit at 5A?

Third question: If removing the resistor, then short the circuit. Assuming the resistance of the wire is 0.0001 Ohm, so regarding to ohm law the current comes through is 5v/0.0001=50,000A and the voltage drop is 50,000/0.0001=500,000,000V. This never can happen in realty, right? I believe in the best case, the circuit can just draw the maximum of 5A.

Can anyone give me a confirmation on this?

Thanks & regard.

Comment: V = IR not I/R.

Comment: What Brian said and...  You should post sketches of your circuit.  It's very very hard to convey these concepts through just words.   Even what you say is "simple", but to avoid mistakes and confusion, a picture is extremely valuable.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: thanks for correction.

Comment: Just as guys said - you got the law wrong - in your third question you're saing that I=U/R and V=I/R. The first one is correct and the other one is not.
You got the current right, but if you use the correct formula for voltage you will get:
0.0001R*50000A=5V, not 500,000,000V

Comment: According to your first question, check out basic Kirchoff's laws. You can get from the first one that all the elements must distribute voltage drops over them to match the source voltage. No such thing here as circuit voltage (in the way you think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the voltage drop in the resistor is 5v, so it makes the voltage across
>   the circuit is 0v

The voltage *around* the circuit is zero. So you have +5 V across the resistor and - 5V across the power source, for a total of 0 V. But the voltage across the 1 Ω resistor is still 5 V (which it has to be because you said it had 5 A going through it), and the voltage across the power supply is still 5 V (which it has to be to put 5 V across the resistor).

Here's your circuit. Note the polarity of the power source relative to current flow around the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQyWXq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> change the resistor value to 0.5 Ohm. In theory, it will draw
>   5v/0.5ohm=10A current, and the voltage drop is 10A/0.5ohm=20v instead.
>   In practice, Will this ever happens?

Your voltage calculation is wrong. \$R = V / I\$, so \$V = I * R\$. You got 10 A by *dividing* 5 V by 0.5 Ω (which is correct), so you get the voltage back by *multiplying* 10 A by 0.5 Ω. Any other result *has* to be wrong because you started with 5 V so you must get back 5 V.

> If removing the resistor, then short the circuit. Assuming the
>   resistance of the wire is 0.0001 Ohm, so regarding to ohm law the
>   current comes through is 5v/0.0001=50,000A... This never can happen in
>   realty, right? I believe in the best case, the circuit can just draw
>   the maximum of 5A.

Ohm's law cannot be violated. If the power supply can deliver 50000 A while maintaining 5 V then 50000 A will flow. That's a lot of current so the power supply (and load) would have to be pretty big, but it's possible. The [Tiwai Point aluminium smelter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiwai_Point_Aluminium_Smelter) had an 800 MW hydroelectric dam built just to power it. The bauxite is reduced to aluminium by passing a DC current of 100-300 kA (thousand amps) through it at ~4.5 V.

Comment: Bruce,  your name looks familiar. Woops, does the designation “A3” hold meaning?  Would you contact me? (see my profile).